# HTTP Error 400 Bad request

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration.

Here my controller:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/restCallBack" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String performCallBack(@RequestBody RestCallBack restCallBack) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull( restCallBack );

    return "computerList";

    }
```

but when I put this on the browser I get a 400:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/restCallBack?devideId=devideId&time=time&duplicate=duplicate&snr=snr&station=station&data=data&avgSignal=avgSignal&lat=lat&lng=lng&rssi=rssi&seqNumber=seqNumber
```

Here the RestCallBack class

```
public class RestCallCallBack {

    private String devideId;

    private String time;

    private String duplicate;

    private String snr;

    private String station;

    private String data;

    private String avgSignal;

    private String lat;

    private String lng;

    private String rssi;

    private String seqNumber;

    public String getDevideId() {
        return devideId;
    }

    public void setDevideId(String devideId) {
        this.devideId = devideId;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDuplicate() {
        return duplicate;
    }

    public void setDuplicate(String duplicate) {
        this.duplicate = duplicate;
    }

    public String getSnr() {
        return snr;
    }

    public void setSnr(String snr) {
        this.snr = snr;
    }

    public String getStation() {
        return station;
    }

    public void setStation(String station) {
        this.station = station;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getAvgSignal() {
        return avgSignal;
    }

    public void setAvgSignal(String avgSignal) {
        this.avgSignal = avgSignal;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getRssi() {
        return rssi;
    }

    public void setRssi(String rssi) {
        this.rssi = rssi;
    }

    public String getSeqNumber() {
        return seqNumber;
    }

    public void setSeqNumber(String seqNumber) {
        this.seqNumber = seqNumber;
    }


}
```

Comment: why are you returning null? Return a string.. In your case restCallBack

Comment: the only purpose is to create an object restCallBack in the DB

Comment: I think view renders the value returned by the controller.  I'm not sure why are you returning null..  Even if you create restCallBack object for db,  it's better you fetch the value from db and return to view..  Correct me if I'm wrong.!

Comment: How is Spring supposed to instantiate a `RestCallBack` object? What is that? What is your request body?

Comment: It looks like you want `@ModelAttribute`, not `@RequestBody`.

Comment: Look for examples using @RequestParams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example request query string, it seems like you are attempting to pass request parameters to the server rather than a request body. If so, take a look at `@RequestParam`, e.g.

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/restCallBack" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String performCallBack(@RequestParam("devideId") String devideId, 
            @RequestParam("time") String time,
            @RequestParam("duplicate") String duplicate,
            /* more request params... */ {

        RestCallCallBack restCallCallBack = new RestCallCallBack();
        restCallCallBack.setDevideId(devideId);
        restCallCallBack.setTime(time);
        restCallCallBack.setDuplicate(duplicate);
        // set more params...

        // perform validation
        return "computerList";
    }
}
```

You can also specify which params are optional by by setting the `@RequestParam`'s `required` attribute to `false`.

More information available in the [Binding request parameters to method parameters with @RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) paragraph in the Spring Reference docs.